# Lets Encrypt: repair broken certificate with certbot

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

How can I run certbot to re-issue a specific (or all) certificate(s), if configuration is broken. E.g. if the content of folder `letsencrypt/live` was deleted accidentally.
Using `renew` I get an error and certbot skips. Is there an option like `force-reinstall-if-broken` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `certbot certonly` with the actual configuration should work.

```
certbot certonly --config /path/to/config.conf
```

Being `config.conf` a Letsencrypt config file like this:

```
domains = url.com, www.url.com
rsa-key-size = 4096

# the current closed beta (as of 2015-Nov-07) is using this server
server = https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

email = user@email.com
text = True

# authenticate by placing a file in the webroot (under .well-known/acme-challenge/)
# and then letting LE fetch it
authenticator = webroot
webroot-path = /path/to/webroot
```

Note that I am using the `webroot` plugin to generate the cert, so I can avoid any downtime in my server.

When writing a script to create and automatize my certs I had to reissue the certifications many times and this command worked for me without having to delete anything extra.

If you are still in trouble, try to symbolic link in `renew` to the latest `.pem` certificate archives of your server:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 mar 11 01:02 cert.pem -> ../../archive/[SERVER]/cert8.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 mar 11 01:02 chain.pem -> ../../archive/[SERVER]/chain8.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 mar 11 01:02 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/[SERVER]/fullchain8.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 mar 11 01:02 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/[SERVER]/privkey8.pem
```

Comment: thanks. with config.conf you mean a certain webserver conf file, something like /etc/nginx/conf.d/abcdef.conf? If I try this I get an error because the file structure. So it seems with config.conf you mean another conf file? I found it should be e.g. cli.ini, but I don't have such files.

Comment: ok, I found I can create such a file cli.ini, containing e.g. "domains = my.domain.com". But running the suggested command I get an error "Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t". I understand "certonly" means not considering a certain webserver? btw, the official docu says "it is incorrect to list domains in it".

Comment: The .conf file is a Letsencrypt config file. I use the `webroot` plugin that works perfectly with Nginx and other servers different to Apache. With `certonly` you are getting a TLS/SSL certificate without installing it anywhere (check more in manual with `certbot --help certonly`). I updated my answer with the info related to the webroot plugin and the config file.

Answer (score 1):

**certbot certificates**

***Find the path to the fullchain certificate you wish to reinstall***

`certbot revoke --cert-path /etc/letsencrypt/live/...` 
path to the cert from above

`certbot delete --cert-name yourdomain.com`

`rm -Rf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf` 
or whatever the name of the apache conf you had it configured on

`rm -Rf 000-default-le-ssl.conf` 
or whatever the name of the apache conf you had it configured on

`sudo apache2ctl restart`

`certbot` 
follow the guide to setup the new certificate